# Quickest way to load multiple csvs into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, numpy

I have a folder which contains many csvs (100+) and each csv contains many rows.

I am using the following code to load the csv into data frame, but it take a fair amount of time. What is the quickest way to load this data?

```
import os
import glob
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

path = '/Users/DATA'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv'))

np_array_list = []
for file_ in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col = None, header = 0, low_memory = False,
                     usecols = [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 22, 23])
    np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())

comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list)
big_data = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dfs = []
for file_ in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(...)
    dfs.append(df)

big_data = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This avoids turning your DataFrames into NumPy arrays and back again.

If that's still not fast enough, use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) to read several at a time, the concat them at the end.

Comment: Thanks John! that halved the processing time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a generator expression to avoid loading all data into memory twice.

```
dfs = (pd.read_csv(file_, **kwargs) for file_ in all_files)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

You can also try passing the `engine='c'` argument to the reader as well to speed things up a bit.

Comment: Sorry, but I seem to get the name 'kwargs' is not defined.

Comment: @h.choi **kwargs is a python convention for unpacking key word arguments. In your case, these are those optional arguments that you are passing to read_csv ie. (index_col = None, header = 0, low_memory = False) etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy-loadtxt)

If you wish to use NumPy and your data is clean, you can bypass `pd.read_csv` altogether:

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv'))
cols_to_use = [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 22, 23]

arr = np.vstack([np.loadtxt(fn, delimiter=',', usecols=cols_to_use) for fn in all_files])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Comment: Sorry, but my data must not be clean. (it says it could not convert string to float:

Comment: @h.choi, You should give an example of your data [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53463553/edit) so we know what you mean.